# Can anyone find a K3,3 subdivision on the Petersen Graph?

Tags: graph-theory

Where is the K3,3 subdivision on the Petersen Graph? I am unable to understand the drawing on the [Kuratowski's Theorem Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem)

[image: Petersen subgraph as subdivision of forbidden K{3,3}]

Comment: @MorganRodgers: It is not at all clear that the OP intended to ask about the generalized graph in the figure. My understanding of the question is that he wanted to find a $K_{3,3}$ subdivision of the _standard_ Petersen graph and could not understand how the image he had located would help him do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take only the sub-graph composed of those vertices which are connected by the red arcs. Start smoothing it out. The red vertices will disappear, and you will end up with $K_{3,3}$ composed of green and blue vertices - the green and the blue vertices being on the two opposite sides, i.e. all arcs after the smoothing will be of the type $(green\space vertex, blue\space vertex)$

Comment: The graph on the Wikipedia page has 18 vertices, and I was able to do it with 12 vertices. Have I done something wrong?

Comment: It really might help for you to see what I did. Never mind.

Answer (score 4):

The graph in the image you show is not THE Petersen graph -- the caption describes is as a particular *generalized* Petersen graph.

The simplest way to show that the ordinary 10-vertex Petersen graph is not planar is to contract each of the 5 "spokes" in the usual drawing. This results in $K_5$, one of the forbidden minors.

There's *also* a $K_{3,3}$ subdivision of the same kind as your figure shows, however:

[image: standard Petersen graph with K_{3,3} subdivision]

Comment: So a $K_{3,3}$ subdivision in the petersen is the 3 blue and 3 green vertices?